# Why is it necessary to create a lot of different exception types?

Tags: java

Most of the time, if I want to terminate the execution of the program at a certain critical point, I just create a RuntimeException with some informational messages:

```
throw new RuntimeException("ERROR: this is wrong! Fix it first!")
```

In Java there are lots of different built-in exception types, and books also teach how to create your own custom exception types. Is that really necessary? Isn't a RuntimeException sufficient for most purposes from a practical point point of view?

Answer (score 2):

*Most of the time, if I want to terminate the execution of the program at a certain critical point*

Most of the time I don't want to terminate my application but I want to recover from exception to continue execution.

In general, you dont have to define your own exceptions as you could (technically) use only eg. `Exception` and `RuntimeException` but creating your own exception classes allowes you to fine graing catching of such exceptions. For example

```
try{
   myService.doSomething();
}catch(MyCustomException){
 //handle custom exception here- eg.
  retunr Constants.DEFAULT_RESPONSE;
}catch(RuntimeException e){
  log.error("Unknown Error",e);
  return null;
}
```

So in this scenario I allow myself to recover from exception thrown by my service method but in the same time I am loggin all others exceptions (returning `null` is not hte best practice what so ever)

Answer (score 1):

I strongly discourage the use of generic `RuntimeException` and `Exception`.  This is to allow us to be able to handle different exceptions in different ways.

For example, if I catch a `RuntimeException`, I would want to do a different action if it's due to bad input (so we can tell the user to fix their input), a disk error (so we can alert the operations team so they can replace), or a null pointer (which is clearly a bug).  Throwing and catching generic `RuntimeException`s make this more difficult than is really necessary.

Comment: As I think that what you have in mind, I disagree with stance to not to use RunitimeExceptions. To me it is a common practice to eg. wrap ungandled exceptions into RuntimeExceptions and rethrow.

Answer (score 0):

One way having different types of exceptions is useful is that you can define how your program should behave in response to a particular exception being thrown.

```
try {
    // code that may throw several types of exceptions
} catch (Exception1 e) {
    // handle Exception1
} catch (Exception2 e) {
    // handle Exception2
} catch ...
```

In this way a running program may recover from an exception and may continue running.

Comment: How this differs from mine or Joe C's answer?